# How to create a new data frame with the sum of the values of a column every n seconds in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, sum

I need to create a new DataFrame with the sum of the values of the AA column every 0.1 seconds.
Is there any function that can do this easily?

```
Time AA

0.003 362
0.02  152
0.1   65
0.15  63
0.2   58
0.26  567
0.3   45
0.32  45
0.3   69 
...
```

Expected output:

```
time    sum
0-0.1   514
0.1-0.2 128
0.2-0.3 1147
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df["rounded_down"] = df["Time"].apply(lambda x: np.floor(x * 10) / 10)
df["rounded_up"] = df["Time"].apply(lambda x: np.ceil(x * 10) / 10)
# Assuming values get grouped upward (so .3 is in .3-.4,
# you can change this by switching to subtracting from rounded_down)
df.loc[df["rounded_down"] == df["rounded_up"], "rounded_up"] += 0.1
df["time"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: str(round(x["rounded_down"], 1)) + "-" + str(round(x["rounded_up"], 1)), 
    axis=1)
# Calculate result
result = df.groupby("time")["AA"].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!